# Hyperledger Fabric: How to generate certificates using openssl?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Does anyone know how to use [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/docs/) to generate certificate and keys that can be used with Hyperledger Fabric? Examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used OpenSSL first hand to generate certificates but someone on [Rocketchat](https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/fabric-sdk-go) said `the Go sdk uses Fabric's encryption, which is compatible with openssl... see this integration test example that imports openssl ch config signatures into the sdk`.

This [link](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/blob/master/test/integration/e2e/orgs/multi_orgs_ch_update_signatures_test.go#L85) to integration test may be helpful.

Sorry If it doesn't solve your problem, and feel free to head to [Rocketchat](https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/fabric), someone will probably help you out there.